# Replaced motherboard, now I see "missing operating system". What to do?

Tags: motherboard, operating-systems

So I've just installed my new mobo and CPU. When I try to boot it up I get the message "missing operating system" on my screen. I tried to select my other drive but that didn't work either. I tried to Google but can't find a similar situation or question at all, so I feel like this is not normal (or it is, so that's why there's no questions). What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens when you put in a USB flash drive with another OS, e.g. Linux?

Comment: This sounds like a UEFI/Legacy/Compatability Mode issue.  If you installed Windows on a GPT partition then you need to enable UEFI mode if you installed it on an MBR partition, then you need to enable Compability Mode/Legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you maybe have not configured the Windows installation correctly before moving it. Your old mobo may have an old-style legacy BIOS in it, and your new one has a UEFI in it with CSM. This means that the board is backwards-compatible but the OS is not configured correctly. The best way to go about this is a fresh reinstallation if Windows. But, there are possible workarounds.

The one I would recommend is to use Windows installation media to repair your computer. I will assume you have Windows 10. You have to get Windows install media (off a different computer with a UEFI, this is required) with the free Media Creation Tool. After you create the media, you have to turn off your own computer completely and boot from the USB.

When you get to the startup for Windows installation, click on the specified language and keyboard, and click on “Repair my computer” at the bottom left. Try to do an automated repair first. If it doesn’t detect any Windows installations, however, it won’t fix the problem.

If that does happen, you will have to press Ctrl-Shift-F10 to get to a CMD prompt. When you are there, make a new EFI partition if you don’t have one with Diskpart.

```
create partition efi size=100
```

Mount it using:

```
assign letter=<a letter you don’t use, like X>
```

When you have done that, then you can exit Diskpart with `exit`and use the bcdboot command to fix your boot.

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s X: /f UEFI
```

Modify the command according to your needs as described by the Microsoft docs on bcdboot, which you can find on Google.

After that, boot from your normal hard drive again and you should be good.

Comment: The Media Creation Tool doesn't require a specific type of firmware to create a USB. The resulting media is bootable in UEFI or legacy regardless of the type of firmware. I've done it in an old BIOS computer and used to install in UEFI mode to another and vice-versa.

Comment: I’ve had computers where on older builds of Windows 10, a specific build for either UEFI or BIOS was created if you were creating directly using the Media Creation Tool. This is why I started using Rufus, and I do recommend that for that reason.

Comment: I think you got your apps confused :) Booting in one mode only is what Rufus does for Linux if not using the dd option. the first ones I mentioned before were done 2 years ago, don remember which build I had.